# SVN multi-version Mac client Xversion and Cornerstone

Tags: macos, svn

I'm currently looking for a Mac Subversion client with multi-version support. There currently only seems to be two available, Xversion and Cornerstone. Anyone had any experience with any of these clients or can recommend any others?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this *multi-version support*? What exactly makes you look for such client? Note that SVN servers and clients of different versions are compatible with each other.

Comment: Would you not think it better to work with the version your client is using? They may not all be using the same version in which case I'd prefer to use there version they are using.

Comment: I think that it's OK as a general practice. But in case of SVN I'd advise the latest 1.9.x client versions. If you access the repositories via HTTP(S) or svnserve's protocol there is no practical reason to use outdated or different client versions (unless there is some very special case).